# facebook c# SDK in Windows Store app LoginButton will not render in Designer

Tags: facebook, windows-store-apps, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using VS2013 following the tutorial [facebooksdk login-ui-control](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/controls/login-ui-control/) once I get to step 9 my Design view does not render and if I hover over facebookControls:LoginButton in the XAML I show an error "ResourceMap not found"

I am using

Facebook C# SDK Version: 6.0.10.0

Facebook SDK for Windows & Windows Phone Version: 0.8.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

Facebook SDK version 6.4.2
Facebook.Client version 0.8.5-alpha

targetFramework win81

but after first F5 the control starts working OK. Seems *.PRI files did not load correctly. see http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/jfowler/post/2013/07/15/ResourceMap-Not-Found-Exception-message.aspx